# Is it possible be use directlua substitutions inside listings environment?

Tags: listings, luatex, lua, luacode

is it possible to insert a directlua substitution inside a listings environment?

for example -

```
\begin{luacode}
    a=math.random()
    b=math.random()
\end{luacode}

\begin{listings}
    if(\directlua{tex.print(a)} > \directlua{tex.print(b)) {
        result = tex.print(a);
    }
    else {
        result = tex.print(b);
    }
\end{listings}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you mean `lstlisting` environment provided by `listings` package, which is used for typesetting source code listings. It provides `escapechar` option, which defines character that can be used to mark portions of code in which LaTeX macros are executed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode}
    a=math.random()
    b=math.random()
\end{luacode}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=`]
    if(`\directlua{tex.print(a)}` > `\directlua{tex.print(b)}`) {
        result = tex.print(a);
    }
    else {
        result = tex.print(b);
    }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Backtick (`) character is used in this example. As you can see, if you put it around `\directlua` command, it will be expanded:

[image]